# Какой использовать тип для работы с числами размером до 128 бит?

Tags: c#, типы, длинная-арифметика

Мне нужен тип, который позволял бы работать с крупными числами (до 128 бит). Что-то типа BigInteger, но с плавающей точкой. Плюс к этому нужны операция деления и подведение под натуральный логарифм. Есть какой-нибудь подходящий для этого тип?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вам нужен `decimal`. 
128-бит, 28-29 значащих цифр.

Comment: Decimal хоть и 128 бит, но реально там часть битов не используется. @Suvitruf

Comment: Я может не прав? Я считал что используется всё, только не для хранения собственно мантиссы. Например, бит на знак тратится.